# MySQL Date Time Issue

Tags: mysql

I have two date entities, start_date and end_date and now I want to find if current date is between my start_date and end_date, how can I do it in mysql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, it's almost the same in MySQL as it was when you explained it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```